# Is there anyway to run GPT2 without GPU and TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, gpu

GPT2 is an excellent OpenAI project for NLP. The developer requirement stated we need to use tensor Flow and GPU. I only want to use (not to train) the existing trained parameters. Is there any way to use GPT2 without the expensive hardware with GPU and without the need to install of Tensor Flow?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do :

- sess.run([var for var in tf.trainable_variables]) to get trained parameters and save them as numpy array.
- rebuild a numpy only version of gpt2.

But :

- This will take a substantial amount of work to rebuild the model
- You need to install tensorflow at least once to get the trained variables.

As for the gpu, you don't need it actually, the model will run with a cpu version of tensorflow (gpu are especially needed to speed up training time).